# SHA salt in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sha1, salt

I am setting a cookie. Something like:

```
$_COOKIE['test'] = SHA1('124'.'mysalt');
```

Now 124 is my id which I want. So in my MySQL table, I am trying to run a query like:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA1(`id`) = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['test'])."'");
```

How to add the "mysalt" to the SQL query? Because else I want get the correct id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use can use [Concat()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for that.

```
SELECT ... Sha1( Concat(`id`, 'mysalt') )=...
```

Comment: Keep in mind: MySQL cannot use an index to speed up the search in this case. It might be better to add another field to the table , so you can query something like SELECT ... WHERE id=124 AND tempkey='87gesafouvgbaesofiuigsaf'

Answer (score 1):

The query should be:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA1(CONCAT(`id`,`mysalt`)) = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['test'])."'");
```

if I understand correctly what you're trying to do.

Comment: did not check for new answers while I took too long to answer, my bad.

Comment: Doing this is ugly and will make performances collapse as the `users` table will grow because MySQL will have to compute `SHA1(CONCAT('id', 'mysalt'))` each time the request is executed. Consider adding a new column `id_hash` containing `SHA1(CONCAT('id', 'mysalt'))`, index it and place your request filtering on `id_hash = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['test'])`

Answer (score 1):

The solutions already provided probably will work just fine, however are you certain you want to do this? If the field "id" is really a distinct identification you can use "LIMIT 1" to stop mysql from searching thru all your items. Another thing is, why don't you use a separate precomputed field for this? I mean in every query mysql unnecessarily needs to compute all these sha1 values.. One last thing. I'm uncertain why you are using your approach, but my best guess is to implement some sort of session key. I thing this is a bad idea for a couple of reasons: If someone gets holds on your salt, he has access to all your accounts. If someone sniffs one "session" he can reuse it whenever he wants to. Choosing a weak salt could have serious consequences. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Use CONCAT:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE SHA1(CONCAT(`id`,'mysalt')) = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE[''test''])."'");
```

Comment: Why should the OP use concat?